# MySQL Query - Trouble with dates / between

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a 3rd party plugin that displays events, however for some reason whenever there is an event with multiple days, it stops showing the event when the current day is past the start date, even though the end date is still in the future.

The MySQL query appears to be trying to return these with the BETWEEN part after the OR at the end but it never does. I'm not familiar enough with MySQL to see what's wrong I guess.

For instance the row I'm expecting it to return here contains:

```
published=1 
dates=2014-04-17
enddates=2014-04-19
```

SQL:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM eventlist_events AS a 
WHERE a.published = 1 
AND a.dates >= '2014-04-18' 
AND (DATE(a.dates) = DATE_ADD('2014-04-18',INTERVAL 0 DAY)        
     OR ( a.enddates IS NOT NULL 
          AND (DATE_ADD('2014-04-18',INTERVAL 0 DAY) 
                BETWEEN DATE(a.dates) AND DATE(a.enddates))) )
```

Comment: That row doesn't satisfy `a.dates >= '2014-04-18'`.

Comment: I've re-indented your WHERE expression so that the logic is more obvious

Comment: Could you explain the logic that the query is supposed to implement. Why are you adding 0 days to several dates, that doesn't do anything? Maybe if you explained which parts get replaced with user input, it would be clearer.

Comment: You're right it was the first WHERE condition.  I saw the OR and looked at the condition after it independently, but failed to notice it was still restricted by the first condition.  The code as it's embedded in php is not pretty.  Cleaning it up really helped.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To satisfy your where clause for `2014-04-18` fall in between the column values:

```
SELECT a.* FROM eventlist_events AS a 
WHERE a.published = 1 
  AND a.enddates IS NOT NULL 
  AND '2014-04-18' BETWEEN DATE(a.dates) AND DATE(a.enddates)
```

And if you want to fetch when `a.enddates` too is null, then

```
SELECT a.* FROM eventlist_events AS a 
WHERE a.published = 1 
  -- AND a.enddates IS NOT NULL 
  AND '2014-04-18' 
         BETWEEN DATE( a.dates ) 
             AND DATE( IFNULL( a.enddates, a.dates ) )
```